# How to obtain the current Local Area Code (LAC) of the handset in Android?

Tags: android

I want to obtain the current Local Area Code of the Cell the handset is currently loged in to. 
How do I get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current Local Area code you have to get a [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

then you can get a [Gs,CellLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html) from the TelephonyManager.

```
GsmCellLocation location = (((GsmCellLocation)tm.getCellLocation());
```

the GsmCellLocation has a [getLac](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html#getLac%28%29) Method that returns the current LAC.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cell to which you are connected in the following way:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCellLocation%28%29

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellLocation cl = tm.getCellLocation();
if (cl instanceof GsmCellLocation) {
    GsmCellLocation gcl = (GsmCellLocation) cl;
    int lac = gcl.getLac();
}
```

Comment: +one for checking type of CellLocation

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo()[n].getLac()
```

Comment: How do I see which of the cells from the list am I connected to, or does the list only contains the neighbour cells?

Comment: I think that this is only the list of cells you are connected to.

Comment: You are only connected to one cell at a time, the cells in the list are the cells that you could also be connected to.