# How to get IMEI, LAC/CELLID in android

Tags: java, iphone, android, xcode

how to get IMEI, data of LAC/CELLID? Is it easy? in android/iphone?
Could you please drop me few lines?

Comment: [IMEI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679120/uniquely-identify-an-android-handset) and [LAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276317/how-to-obtain-the-current-local-area-code-lac-of-the-handset-in-android) for Android. Search is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

For IMEI
does it

```
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();
```

with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), like following lines:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
String IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();
int lac = location.getLac();
... ...
```

Also, you should use the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Hope it helps.